# Choose best path location and method to read/write file php

Tags: php, file, read-write

I am developing a REST web service script which reads/writes a file. This web service is called more than 10 times per second.

There are two type of folder structure.

First

```
public_html/files/file.txt
public_html/ws/script.php

file_put_contents('../files/file.txt', $data);
$file=file_get_contents('../files/file.txt');
```

Second

```
public_html/ws/files/file.txt
public_html/ws/script.php

file_put_contents('files/file.txt', $data);
$file=file_get_contents('files/file.txt');
```

My Questions:

1. In the above two types, which is faster and has better performance?
2. There are ways to read/write files. Are there better ways than above?

Thanks

Comment: There is no difference between the two

Comment: You are likely to have a serious file access contention problem with that level on concurrency.  You might want to rethink using disk i/o for whatever it is you are trying to do. that being said,I don't think there would be any meaningful difference between your two options. Of course you can test this your self.

Comment: Mr. relentless and Mr. Mike Brant, thank you for your reply.

Comment: You should not keep files in public_html that are supposed to be accessed through a script. Second, why access them through a script? If you only read and output the file your websever will do that probably faster than a php script. To avoid name clashes with uploaded files, you should include a unique_id in the file path/name. PHP allows to [passthru files](http://php.net/fpassthru) if you do not need to alter anything when handing them out, that might be the better choice, also look at [readfile](http://php.net/readfile)